# Как убрать over-scroll в ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Есть `XML` разметка активности. В ней `ScrollView` в котором, в свою очередь находится `ImageView`. После компиляции, при скроллинге этой картинки, возникает так называемый `Over-scroll`, когда "высота" `ScrollView` больше чем содержание этого `ScrollView`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На англ. StackOverflow нашел [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169567/how-could-i-disable-all-the-over-scroll-effect-in-my-app) вариант решения проблемы:
`listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);`, который у меня, к сожалению, не работает.

Код активности с этим `ScrollView`:

```
public class screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_screen);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        scroll.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.help);
```

`XML` код активности:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="helmus.myapplication.MainActivity">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
</ScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я догадываюсь, что это не overscroll, а ошибка в верстки. Два очевидных решения.

1. Установить картинку как background, пример:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="helmus.myapplication.MainActivity">
   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/scroll">

       <ImageView
           android:background="@drawable/img"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/img" />
   </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Картинка растянется по ImageView и не будет видно границ, минус в том, что предварительно нужно иметь заранее правильно отформатированную картинку, чтоб она не искажалась.

2. Выровнять по видимым границам:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="helmus.myapplication.MainActivity">
   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/scroll">

       <ImageView
           android:src="@drawable/img"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/img" />
   </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

У этого варианта тоже есть свои минусы, но мне кажется, это именно то что Вам подойдет. Вот теперь можете убрать или поставить эффект overscroll и понять в чем разница. Удачи.